# Eclipse - Tomcat 7 - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException on publish

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat7

I have a Webproject using maven and when I try to deploy it to Tomcat 7, I get the following message:

```
Publishing failed
Could not publish to the server.
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
Could not publish server configuration: myworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified.). 
myworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified.)
```

When I look at the log file of tomcat in 'myworkpace.metadata.logs' I see the following:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2013-11-22 13:36:40.128
!MESSAGE Publishing failed
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2013-11-22 13:36:40.128
!MESSAGE Could not publish to the server.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.Util.getInputStreamAsByteArray(Util.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.ToolFactory.createDefaultClassFileReader(ToolFactory.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.JavaEEArchiveUtilities.isEJBArchive(JavaEEArchiveUtilities.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.JavaEEArchiveUtilities.refineForJavaEE(JavaEEArchiveUtilities.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.JavaEEArchiveUtilities.openArchive(JavaEEArchiveUtilities.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.JavaEEArchiveUtilities.openBinaryArchive(JavaEEArchiveUtilities.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper$ArchiveCache.openArchive(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:612)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.openArchive(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.getUniqueArchive(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.getArchive(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.getJavaEEQuickPeek(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.JavaEEProjectUtilities.getJ2EEComponentType(JavaEEProjectUtilities.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.common.exportmodel.JEEHeirarchyExportParticipant.isChildModule(JEEHeirarchyExportParticipant.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.isChildModule(FlatVirtualComponent.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.addUsedReferences(FlatVirtualComponent.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.treeWalk(FlatVirtualComponent.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.cacheResources(FlatVirtualComponent.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.fetchResources(FlatVirtualComponent.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.internal.deployables.FlatComponentDeployable.members(FlatComponentDeployable.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.deployables.J2EEFlexProjDeployable.members(J2EEFlexProjDeployable.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ModulePublishInfo.getDelta(ModulePublishInfo.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ServerPublishInfo.getDelta(ServerPublishInfo.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.getPublishedResourceDelta(Server.java:1574)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.getPublishedResourceDelta(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.getPublishedResourceDelta(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:958)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.PublishOperation2.publishDir(PublishOperation2.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.PublishOperation2.execute(PublishOperation2.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.performTasks(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:1335)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:954)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core 4 0 2013-11-22 13:36:40.128
!MESSAGE Could not publish server configuration: C:\IBM\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified.).
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: myworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified.)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatVersionHelper.publishCatalinaContextConfig(TomcatVersionHelper.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.Tomcat70Configuration.publishContextConfig(Tomcat70Configuration.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.publishFinish(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:1011)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

If I try to publish again, I only get the first error:

```
Could not publish to the server.
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

and in the logs:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2013-11-22 13:41:18.645
!MESSAGE Could not publish to the server.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.Util.getInputStreamAsByteArray(Util.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.ToolFactory.createDefaultClassFileReader(ToolFactory.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.JavaEEArchiveUtilities.isEJBArchive(JavaEEArchiveUtilities.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.JavaEEArchiveUtilities.refineForJavaEE(JavaEEArchiveUtilities.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.JavaEEArchiveUtilities.openArchive(JavaEEArchiveUtilities.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.JavaEEArchiveUtilities.openBinaryArchive(JavaEEArchiveUtilities.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper$ArchiveCache.openArchive(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:612)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.openArchive(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.getUniqueArchive(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.getArchive(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.getJavaEEQuickPeek(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.JavaEEProjectUtilities.getJ2EEComponentType(JavaEEProjectUtilities.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.common.exportmodel.JEEHeirarchyExportParticipant.isChildModule(JEEHeirarchyExportParticipant.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.isChildModule(FlatVirtualComponent.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.addUsedReferences(FlatVirtualComponent.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.treeWalk(FlatVirtualComponent.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.cacheResources(FlatVirtualComponent.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.fetchResources(FlatVirtualComponent.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.internal.deployables.FlatComponentDeployable.members(FlatComponentDeployable.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.deployables.J2EEFlexProjDeployable.members(J2EEFlexProjDeployable.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ModulePublishInfo.fillCache(ModulePublishInfo.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ModulePublishInfo.getDelta(ModulePublishInfo.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ServerPublishInfo.getDelta(ServerPublishInfo.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.getPublishedResourceDelta(Server.java:1574)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.getPublishedResourceDelta(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.getPublishedResourceDelta(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:958)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.computeDelta(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I tried starting from a clean installation (clean eclipse, clean tomcat and clean workspace), imported the code from CVS, but still the same problem

Anyone got any ideas as to what may be incorrect (or how I could locate the problem)?

**EDIT**

When I build the project into a WAR-file on another computer and deploy this war file directly to tomcat via the management console, it works.

My guess is that the build must be different somehow...

**EDIT2**

I removed the complete maven repository. Afer this, I was able to build the project correctly and run it on Tomcat using the exported war-file.

However, I still get the IndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to publish directly from eclipse

**EDIT3**

After removing the Maven repository a few times, I was able to build and run the project. It seems Maven sometimes gets corrupted.

If others should have this problem, delete the complete Maven directory and run a maven update on each of the projects in the workspace.

Comment: The solution in EDIT3 worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: where should I delete the Maven directory? in Eclipse or Maven installed dir?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The maven repository can be corrupt. It is best to remove the complete repository and update all projects in the workspace.

Comment: I was faced with the same problem, but deleting the repository and updating project did not work. Any alternatives?

Comment: My maven repo size is really huge so that I don't want to delete all files in it. So May I delete the directory by the name "org"? I think every classes in the stacktrace starts with org. @dshgna

Comment: This fixed my issue. However you don't need to delete the entire repository, Instead, you can do a maven install on the project. It will show the corrupted jar files in the build log. This will save having to delete and download the entire repository again.

Answer (score 4):

Although this question has been answered - it was a problem with a corrupt repository, it is possible to determine which jar in your repository is corrupt by deploying the war to Tomcat outside of eclipse.

In my situation Tomcat then reported in its log where the problem lay (guava-13.0.1.jar):

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [com/google/common/collect/package-info.class] from Jar
[jar:file:/C:/Java/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/guava-13.0.1.jar!/] for annotations
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Comment: I was showing how it was possible to determine which Jar file was corrupt - something that isn't evident when experiencing the problem in Eclipse.

Comment: How to deploy to Tomcat outside of eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably some jar of your local maven repo that are included in your .war as dependency are corrupted. 
As jtsnr suggested, you can deploy your .war outside Eclipse to discover which jar is corrupted. But there is a quicker solution. Just locate the /target dir of your maven project (or just unzip the .war) and locate inside the *.jar files (should be under WEB-INF/lib). 
Now, with a simple zip tool (e.g.: 7-Zip) select all and extract. You will receive a prompt for each corrupted file you have: after this, locate the file in your Maven repo and delete the entire version for that file. 
In this way, if you have a big repo, you gain a lot of time avoiding to re-download the entire jar ecosystem :)
HTH..

Comment: That is really the best answer. Deleting the entire library whenever this occurs does not seem to be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try once the way it is mentioned below. so please delete the previous installation.
Step 1
Create a new Server run time
(Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments). 
Step 2
Add Server to Eclipse
(Window -> Show View -> Servers) add a new server configuration (right-click and select New -> Server) but DO NOT ADD ANY PROJECTS TO IT.
Step 3
Open Server Overview page
 Double click the new server configuration to bring up the Server Overview page where we set port and time out for the Server.
Step 4

Under Server Locations select Use Tomcat installation.  Save.

You should be able to start your server now. Now add your project to the server and you're ready to go.

Comment: When I do that, I still get the second error:
    Could not publish to the server.
        java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Are you able to start the server independently without using Eclipse

Comment: Yes, if I import the war file of the same code built on another machine, and import it directly in tomcat without using eclipse, the application runs fine. I've edited my post including this new discovery. I believe there must be something wrong in building the code, not actually running it.