# tomcat Server Error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

This question may sound duplicate but it is not. I am working through a spring application but at this point I am not able to start tomcat. I am getting following errors from tomcat:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.Util.getInputStreamAsByteArray(Util.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.ToolFactory.createDefaultClassFileReader(ToolFactory.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.JavaEEArchiveUtilities.isEJBArchive(JavaEEArchiveUtilities.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.JavaEEArchiveUtilities.refineForJavaEE(JavaEEArchiveUtilities.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.JavaEEArchiveUtilities.openArchive(JavaEEArchiveUtilities.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.JavaEEArchiveUtilities.openBinaryArchive(JavaEEArchiveUtilities.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper$ArchiveCache.openArchive(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:612)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.openArchive(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.getUniqueArchive(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.getArchive(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.componentcore.JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.getJavaEEQuickPeek(JavaEEBinaryComponentHelper.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.JavaEEProjectUtilities.getJ2EEComponentType(JavaEEProjectUtilities.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.common.exportmodel.JEEHeirarchyExportParticipant.isChildModule(JEEHeirarchyExportParticipant.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.GlobalHeirarchyParticipant.isChildModule(GlobalHeirarchyParticipant.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.isChildModule(FlatVirtualComponent.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.addUsedReferences(FlatVirtualComponent.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.treeWalk(FlatVirtualComponent.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.cacheResources(FlatVirtualComponent.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.fetchResources(FlatVirtualComponent.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.internal.deployables.FlatComponentDeployable.members(FlatComponentDeployable.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.deployables.J2EEFlexProjDeployable.members(J2EEFlexProjDeployable.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ModulePublishInfo.fillCache(ModulePublishInfo.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ModulePublishInfo.getDelta(ModulePublishInfo.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ServerPublishInfo.getDelta(ServerPublishInfo.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.getPublishedResourceDelta(Server.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.getPublishedResourceDelta(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.getPublishedResourceDelta(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:958)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.computeDelta(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3182)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

I am not able to understand this error. So, Please help me to resolve this error.

Turned out its a bug, Has anyone solved it yet?

```
org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.ListLineTracker.getLineNumberOfOffset(ListLineTracker.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractLineTracker.getLineNumberOfOffset(AbstractLineTracker.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.getLineOfOffset(AbstractDocument.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleDocument.getLineOfOffset(ConsoleDocument.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsolePatternMatcher$MatchJob.run(ConsolePatternMatcher.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Comment: try to change the version of your tomcat

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I have added stacktrace after changing tomcat 9 to tomcat 8

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145399/eclipse-tomcat-7-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-on-publish

Comment: @RC. Thanks for comment but I have already tried that and with no luck I am still getting error

Comment: at what point this error started to pop out? what have you changed recently when it occurred? stop the tomcat process, delete "work" directory of tomcat and start it once again

Comment: @DevDio when ever I am starting server for web application. And I am still getting that error with same description.

Comment: Are you getting this error when you copy your application and start the tomcat server or just starting the tomcat server without even your application copied?

Comment: @user7036414 have you tried to delete "work" dir?

Comment: I have two applications one is web and other is rest api. Rest api is working fine but I am getting this error with web application.

Comment: @DevDio I removed `work` but no success.

Comment: how do you deploy rest api?